# Is trim and htmlspecialchars safe?

Tags: php, mysql, xss

I have a little script which allows the user to save a text in the database. For this I used prepared Statements to prevent any SQL injections. -> The part where the user saves sth. in the DB is safe.

Now I want to output the text of the user, I do this like that:

`echo'Text: '.trim (htmlspecialchars ($text)).'';`

Is this method safe? Are there better solutions? Should I rather prevent inserting all this special chars into the DB?

Comment: what do you mean by `is it safe` ?? outputting doesn't put any of your stored data at risk because it can't be put back into the database

Comment: Make data safe on the way into the database. Presentation of that data is not a security risk as you decide what you want to show.

Comment: Before the data goes into the DB I can use strip_tags and htmlspecialchars?

Comment: what is your little script so we can peer attack it

Comment: You should encode the quotes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Htmlspecialchars will convert all special html symbols in entities like `&lt;`
So, it prevent xss security exception. 
So, we can say, that using htmlspecialchars() is safe-way to display text, which can contains html code.

Comment: Exception: in a URL context. You can supply `javascript:someFunction()` all day long with `htmlspecialchars()`. In general, you want `htmlentities()` with `ENT_QUOTES` instead.

Comment: Scott Arciszewski, it works only when you print it inside <script>. I think, not a good way - to print something inside <script>...</script>, accepted from user. But, if you need to print something in <script>...</script> inside quotes, then using ENT_QUOTES with htmlspecialchars prevent possible xss.

Comment: I note also that I wrote 'safe-way to display text, which can contains html code.', I dont say anything about js.

Comment: What would be the safest (against html, js, xss ...) method to display text?

Comment: Okay, use `htmlentities()` with `ENT_QUOTES` - is a super-duper-secure-way 100% guaranteed not pass any kind of xss in any situation. It safer than htmlspecialchars() in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars is for preventing some kinds of xss attacks, not all